# How do I style child component from parent's SCSS without ng-deep?

Tags: css, angular

I've been trying to style a `BoxedComponent` style from `HeaderComponent` without using `::ng-deep`, but I'm not finding a way to so properly.

The `BoxedComponent` component class contains nothing different but a `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'labs-boxed',
  templateUrl: './boxed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./boxed.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class BoxedComponent {}
```

HTML

```
<div class="boxed">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I created two classes in its SCSS file to use everywhere, but I realized I couldn't still stylize the responsiveness of the component due to the same problem.

```
.boxed {
  /* rules */
}

.tall .boxed {
  height: 500px;
  width: 360px;
}

.squared .boxed {
  height: 340px;
  width: 340px;
}
```

In `HeaderComponent`'s HTML file, I am making use of `labs-boxed` as follows:

```
<div id="who-we-are" class="d-flex justify-content-around">
  <labs-boxed [ngClass]="'tall'">
    <p>
    ...
  ...
...
```

So far it works, but then entering in the SCSS file, I have attempted many ways to access `lab-boxed`'s styles and changing it:

.boxed { ... }
.tall .boxed { ...}

and so on, but without success.

How can I do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Since `BoxedComponent` has `ViewEncapsulation.None` all rules defined in `boxed.component.scss` becomes global. When `HeaderComponent` has default encapsulation, all rules defined in `header.component.scss` are isolated from global scope and becomes specific to `HeaderComponent`. As a matter of fact `ng-deep` works by making single rules global. In other words it removes rules from isolated scope and puts into the global scope and it is the only way of making a single rule global within an encapsulated styles file. Without help of `ng-deep` you can override child component styles in following ways;

1. Apply another global style to child and add related styles to global; `styles.scss` file.

   - in header.component.html

   ```
   <labs-boxed class="custom-box-style">
   ```

   - in styles.scss

   ```
   .custom-box-style .boxed {
     // new rules
   }
   ```
2. Programatically set styles on specific child instance.

   - in header.component.html

   ```
   <labs-boxed #childEl class="squared">squared and red</labs-boxed>
   ```

   - in header.component.ts

   ```
   @ViewChild('childEl', {read: ElementRef, static: true}) childEl: ElementRef;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     const box = this.childEl.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("boxed");
     box[0].style.backgroundColor = "red"
   }
   ```

[Here is a demonstration](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wuf4zt) of both approaches.